# error on some devices

Tags: android

I got this error report from some devices  while on others application is working so fine !!!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hamoosh.birdseffects.De7katGrid$1.onItemClick(De7katGrid.java:44)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1359)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2988)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3783)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where no errors on source code ??

error line is 44 shown in this part of code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            stopPlaying();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(De7katGrid.this, mSongsIds[position]);
            mp.start();// << here is line 44 !!!
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide more information...

Comment: can you provide source code for com.hamoosh.birdseffects.De7katGrid class.

Comment: check please again I added part of the code

Comment: What is the format of your sound file?

Comment: @DeeV ty for asking me that :) I tried mp3 file and It worked fine , so problem is wav file , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaPlayer.create returns null when the sound file at the resource ID is either not supported by the device, doesn't exist, or is corrupt.

In this case, you're using .wav files which may not be supported on certain devices. If you're sampling rate for the file.  They're only guaranteed to be supported on devices 4.1+. Here is the list of supported formats:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html